How to plot anndata like matrix to grey 2d numpy array
Input data

mtx: "<COOrdinate sparse matrix of dtype 'int64' with 357558594 stored elements and shape (30562, 96629557)>"

mtx.todense()[0:2,0:8] = matrix([[4050,   24,   21,    3,    0,    3,    2,    1],
[1437,   17,   17,    3,    0,    3,    2,    1]])


cspdata2d: numpy.ndarray

cspdata2d.shape = (96629557, 2)
cspdata2d[0:8,:] = array([[43426,  1414],
[ 5496, 20015],
[23193, 19957],
[ 2252, 28571],
[10910, 22382],
[ 1385, 19958],
[ 5508, 22828],
[25183, 22533]], dtype=int32)



Output

outimg: np.zeros(shape=cspdata2d.max(axis=0), dtype=np.int16)

outimg.shape = (51968, 40141)




I want to plot values of mtx.todense()[1:2,:] with x,y = cspdata2d[index] to outimg, where index is from the 2nd dimensions of mtx.
It is like scanpy.pl.spatial, but I want to plot to pixels. And scanpy is slow on huge data set.

Here is a relatively-efficient Numpy solution:
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.coo import coo_matrix

# Compute `mtx.toarray()[1:2,:]`
# Time: 0.76 s
selected_row = 1
select = mtx.row == selected_row
assert np.array_equiv(mtx.row[select], selected_row)
slice_data = mtx.data[select]
slice_rows = np.zeros(np.count_nonzero(select))
slice_cols = mtx.col[select]
mtx_sparse_slice = coo_matrix((slice_data, (slice_rows, slice_cols)), shape=(1,mtx.shape[1]))
mtx_dense_slice = mtx_sparse_slice.toarray()

# Compute `x,y = cspdata2d[index]` where index is from the 2nd dimensions of mtx
# Assume cspdata2d contains [x,y] values in each row and not [y,x] ones
# Assume the zeros values are not interesting so they are not included
# Time: 0.42 s
index = mtx_dense_slice[0,:]
nnz_index = np.nonzero(index)[0]
x = cspdata2d[nnz_index,0]
y = cspdata2d[nnz_index,1]

# Compute outimg
# Time: 0.75 s
outimg = np.zeros(shape=cspdata2d.max(axis=0), dtype=np.int16) 
outimg[x, y] = nnz_index.astype(np.int16)

Here is a setup to test this with random values:
mtx_nnz = 357_558_594
mtx_nrows = 30_562
mtx_ncols = 96_629_557
mtx_data = np.random.randint(0, mtx_ncols, size=mtx_nnz).astype(np.int64) # Apparently values <= mtx_ncols
mtx_rows = np.random.randint(0, mtx_nrows, size=mtx_nnz).astype(np.int32)
mtx_cols = np.random.randint(0, mtx_ncols, size=mtx_nnz).astype(np.int32)
mtx = coo_matrix((mtx_data, (mtx_rows, mtx_cols)), shape=(mtx_nrows, mtx_ncols))
del mtx_data, mtx_rows, mtx_ncols # Save some memory space

cspdata2d = np.empty(shape=(mtx_ncols,2), dtype=np.int32)
cspdata2d[:,0] = np.random.randint(0, 51_968, size=mtx_ncols)
cspdata2d[:,1] = np.random.randint(0, 40_141, size=mtx_ncols)

The overall execution time is about 2 seconds on my machine which is relatively fast (though not optimal) for a (sequential) Numpy code considering the significant size of the input data (>=10 GiB data to read/write).

scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((data, (i, j)), [shape=(M, N)]) is great. Set data to selected value list, i to cspdata2d[:,0], j to cspdata2d[:,1]. Then the coo_matrix is the image.

I do not understand mtx_sparse_slice = coo_matrix((slice_data, (slice_rows, slice_cols)), shape=(1,mtx.shape[1])) as an intermediate for image.

This is because while data is filtered just before, it may not be ordered correctly. This can certainly be done with an argsort but sorting is generally rather expensive. Thus, we can build an intermediate COO matrix only to convert it to a dense matrix in order to reorder items quickly. This is the only purpose of mtx_sparse_slice : be converted into the dense matrix mtx_dense_slice. That being said, maybe the order does not matter in your case so this step can be skipped. I just wanted to be safe while writing the code (and get a rather fast code though possibly sub-optimal).
